# How to efficiently use first_or_initialize when records usually already exist

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how to use ActiveRecord to execute the following psuedocode:

```
rows_updated = UPDATE my_table SET my_column="abc" WHERE id=123
if rows_updated == 0 then INSERT INTO my_table (id, my_column) VALUES (123, "abc")
```

The reason for this is most of the time the record already exists. I want to save myself the extra `SELECT` query that `first_or_create!` seems to generate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also different and more elegant solution (from my point of view) for this case
One of the options is using a replace command instead of all this code.

just run:

```
REPLACE INTO my_table (id, my_column) VALUES (123, "abc")
```

this solution works just fine in most cases, but if you have a very high load on this pice of code, you should consider using 
[INSERT .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

First do a find or initialize so that if the id is not there it will create the object. then check if it is new. If new save it else update it.

```
obj= find_or_initialize_by_id(obj)
obj.new_record? ? prod.save! : *update the entry*
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for high-efficiency database solutions and all, but that first query ought to be taking something like 1 or 2 ms, and if it's looking like it's mysteriously less efficient than the update it would partly be because the database may require a physical read to access it -- the update then benefits from that pre-caching.

So unless this operation is a measurably significant performance problem I'd not try to optimise it out.